# Gerar relatório IReport / Jasper Report contendo 2 páginas (com 3 colunas cada) em uma mesma folha em modo paisagem

Tags: java, ireport, jasper-reports

estou fazendo um relatório para um cliente e não estou conseguindo montá-lo de acordo com a sua necessidade. O que ele precisa é gerar um PDF de folha A4 no modo paisagem, contendo cada folha duas páginas (ímpar e par), e cada página com 3 colunas.

Já pesquisei em vários fóruns (tanto aqui no GUJ quanto em outros) mas em nenhum consegui encontrar algo para me ajudar com esta resolução, e já estou atrasado com a entrega deste software, onde só falta este relatório dos produtos.

Para exemplificar melhor, estou enviando neste post a imagem do resultado que preciso.

Por favor pessoal, alguém conhece e/ou já precisou gerar um relatório de duas páginas em 1 mesma folha? As 3 colunas eu consigo gerar, porém somente em 1 página.

Se tiverem alguma idéia, ou também até sugestão de outra maneira para gerar, serão muito bem vindas, pois minhas possibilidades estão muito próximas de esgotadas, por isso preciso e muito da ajuda de vocês.

Estou usando IReport versão 5.6.0

Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: *Para exemplificar melhor, estou enviando neste post a imagem do resultado que preciso.* - Cadê a imagem?

Comment: Eu tinha enviado mas a imagem nao subiu. Agora sim segue ela no post.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre o seu problema e um relatório com uma página de 6 colunas? Uma outra possibilidade (um tanto capenga =/ ) seria apenas orientar seu cliente a usar o software da impressora para imprimir duas páginas por folha...

Comment: Alguma resposta lhe foi útil? Poderia escolher alguma e marcá-la como aceita?

Comment: Eu acho que o conceito do jasper raport está sendo misturado. Você está querendo dizer que quer o detail repetindo 2x no corpo da folha por pagina ? Se for isso, creio que a solução proposta pelo @Nigini seja a mais adequada

Answer (score 1):

Achei [essa thread](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/521686/two-a5-one-a4) discutindo mais ou menos o mesmo problema que o seu. O curioso é que a resposta do Staff da Jasper foi na linha do meu comentário na sua pergunta. =]

Vou copiar o código que foi postado lá com alguns poucos comentários meus. Não testei aqui, mas parece fazer sentido no universo que conheço do JasperReports:

```
//Começa configurando o relatório normalmente!
JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(ResourceUtils.getFile(getFileResourcesJRXML("myjasper_A5.jrxml")));
JasperReport jrRH02 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrRH02, data, dataSource);

getResponse().setContentType("application/pdf");
ServletOutputStream outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
exporter.exportReport();

//Não entendi porquê ele fez isso...    
exporter.reset();
exporter = null;
System.gc();

//Aqui é onde a hackeada começa:
Document document = new Document();
//Define as dimensões da página no braço
document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(jp.getPageWidth(), jp.getPageHeight() * 2)); // This is because A4 Size == 2 * A5
//lê os dados do relatório originalmente produzido (páginas separadas)
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
//cria um novo escritor de PDF usando a configuração acima
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
//Faz um loop que lê as páginas do relatório inicial
// e coloca no relatório novo
//Estranhamente ele deixou a definição do loop incompleto,
// não deve ser difícil completar...
for(int i = 1; i ...){
    document.newPage();
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, jp.getPageHeight()); 
}
outputStream.flush();
document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso eu faria o seguinte:
Na paisagem A4 colocaria 2 `SubReports` com 400 pixels cada devidamente configurado as sobras do tamanho, e no meio vi que tem uma linha vertical, pois bem, adicione uma linha vertical.
Configurar os `SubReports` tanto no `Ireport/JasperStudio` e em código, dividindo minha exibições em duas lista(Uma para cada `SubReport`) para não haver redundância.